# Firebase Android ... Use Query

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get to "sid" in order to put it in query "firebase" But I don't know how to get there because orders "model" with the increase in orders, it increases from 1 to ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/togpF.png)

I tried it this way but it didn't work and this is because of "0" number of orders

```
 String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance( ).getCurrentUser( ).getUid( );
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance( );
 DatabaseReference root = database.getReference( "Requests" );
 Query   query = root.orderByChild( "orders/sid" ).equalTo(currentuser  );
```

[image]

Comment: " 15796235 " this is kay of "Requests"

Comment: " userPhone " = " 0132215131"  is example bro ...

Comment: Firebase Database can only query on a property at a fixed path under each direct child node. Since in your case the value can be under `orders/0/sid` or `/orders/1/sid` the path isn't fixed, and the query isn't possible. You'll need to set up some additional data structure to implement this use-case. See my longer explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: I need any solution
How do I rearrange the data appropriately !?

Comment: Storing a flat list of orders would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase RTDB does not support this kind of query. Firestore might and obviously sql does.
In a NoSQL db you really need to duplicate some data in order to satisfy your queries. This also means you need to maintain data integrity 'manually'. In this example I would suggest you need to maintain another node that is keyed by 'sid' ids and that lists the numbers of the orders that they are associated with. Otherwise, you will need to download all the relevant orders as a snapshot and iterate through them in your app.

Comment: I need any solution
How do I rearrange the data appropriately !?